# Loading .xlsx file throws 'date not well formatted'

Tags: c#, excel, date, exception, ironxl

My code is very simple:

```
var thisWorkBook = WorkBook.LoadExcel(path);
```

I have a manual workaround where I go into the file via Excel/Google Sheets and remove a column. That works. For some reason.

The .xlsx file is a work schedule that has the following organization:

File name: Schedule-2021-10-12

sheet1[hourly - position1]:

| Employee ID | Employee | Position | Date (e.g. 10/12/2021) | Total Hours | Unpaid Breaks | Hourly Rate | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

After the each entry belonging to position1 is listed, column A tallies up cost

sheet2[Schedule - position1]

| Date | Employee | Employee ID | Position | Schedule | Site | Start | End | Unpaid Break | Total Hours | Labor Cost | Status | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Now, the Date in this sheet is not formatted the same way as in sheet1 e.g. 10/12/2021 12:00:00 PM. Removing this column stops the code from throwing the exception. I'd leave it at that except there are 14 sheet in total, 7 of which have that date format, but I only have to remove the column from the first of those sheets to fix the exception. Renaming the file doesn't fix the exception. I didn't expect it to, but black magic and all that.

I found some documentation in IronXL that there's a method I can load 'options' into. However, I'm fairly new the programming and don't know what kind of options I can add or if this could even solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, resolved in [IronXL.Excel](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/) version [2021.11.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronXL.Excel/), released on 2021-10-29

Simply updating to the latest version will remove this issue.

```
PM > Install-Package IronXL.Excel
```

Note: I work for Iron Software

Comment: thanks for acknowledging the issue, resolving it and informing the community @darren.